# Efficient way to replace char from each index of a String array if condition match

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm looking for efficient way to replace specific char from a list of email addresses if the char matches in any index of the array. But it should return the full array list.

my current code:

```
List<String> emailList = new ArrayList<>();
    emailList.addAll(Arrays.asList("testEmail@gmail.com","TestnewEmail+454332@gmail.com","testgmail+4342232545@gmail.com"));
    List<String>  updatedEmail = emailList.stream().filter(a->a.contains("+")).
            map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\+", ""))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    emailList.stream().filter(a->!a.contains("+")).forEach(b->updatedEmail.add(b));

    updatedEmail.stream().forEach(b->System.out.println("email: "+b));
```

Console:

```
email: TestnewEmail454332@gmail.com
email: testgmail4342232545@gmail.com
email: testEmail@gmail.com
```

Comment: Note that `s.replace("+", "")` is better than replaceAll as it avoids regex each call so it is just `emailList.stream().map(s -> s.replace("+", "")).forEach(System.out::println)` or `emailList.stream().map(s -> s.replace("+", "")).toList()`

Comment: Note that for Gmail addresses, emailadress `aaa+bbb@gmail.com` refers to just `aaa@gmail.com`, so the suffix behind the `+` can be used as *label*. However, they're not the same as `aaabbb@gmail.com`, which would be the result of your string replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replaceAll` on all strings and string not having `+` symbol will remains unchanged

```
List<String>  updatedEmail = emailList.stream()
        .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\+", ""))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to modify the original list without using streams and creating a new list, you can do something like:

```
emailList.replaceAll(s -> s.replace("+", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You already use `replaceAll` method and you can directly modify every element in current list and print it with `foreach`.

```
emailList.stream()
                .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\+", ""))
                .forEach(b -> System.out.println("email: " + b));
```